# Match a word register that doesnt followed by log in

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to make a regex that not match a word 'register' that have word 'log in' in this string

```
"active active">Log in / Register</a>

"active active">Register / log in</a>
```

but will match this

```
"active active">Register</a>

"active active">siteRegister</a>
```

It is possible to make the regex..?just try it almost 3 hours..appreciate if you can help

Comment: According to an wise man's saying, once a man faced with a problem thought "Hey, I'll solve that with a regex!". Now that man has two problems.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Really? What's it with all this useless regular expression bashing in developers nowadays? They are a specific tool for a specific job and not exactly hard to understand. You can take your above statement and replace "regex" with almost any other specialized solution and have a grain of truth...

Comment: @MichaelKohl Sure regular expressions can be used for OP's goal, but are they really necessary? Doesn't Ruby have any other much-more effective methods of parsing strings? Why use a regular expression for something that doesn't have alternation, repetition or anything that requires a regular expression? Of course, if you want to go with regular expressions, it will be the developer's problem maintaining them in the future.

Comment: it is a bad idea to scraping html with regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that i think it's bad idea to use regex for this sort of thing, you should try that:

```
"active active">\w*Register\w*<\/a>
```

Comment: thanks man..it works... for this cases..that what i ask..lol.but it is a bad idea to scrape html with regex..im just new on this regex thing